# query has no destination for result data in a function that has a set of instructions in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am trying to automate a set of sentences that I execute several times a day. For this I want to put them in a postgres function and just call the function to execute the sentences consecutively. If everything runs OK then in the end return the SUCCESS value. The following function replicates my idea and the error I am getting when executing the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTable() RETURNS int AS $$
     BEGIN
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE; 
          CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
            (
                    ID integer
            )
             WITH (
                OIDS=FALSE
            );

            insert into MY_TABLE values(1);

            select * from MY_TABLE;
            RETURN 'SUCCESS';
     END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Invocation:

```
select * from createTable();
```

With my ignorance of postgresql I would expect to obtain the SUCCESS value as a return (If everything runs without errors). But the returned message causes me confusion, isn't it the same as a function in any other programming language? When executing the function I get the following message:

> query has no destination for result data   Hint: If you want to
>   discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

Comment: Why would you expect the `SELECT` to throw an error? Just omit it, you don't need it - and you're not using its results, as the message tells you.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I understood the cause of the error and the explanation helped me find the error in the real code where I had several select
with the INTO instruction, but I had a "No destination" SELECT used to initialize a sequence, change SELECT to PERFORM as the message suggests and I could execute the function without any inconvenience.

Comment: How does `select * from MY_TABLE` initialise a sequence?

Comment: The code doesn't belong to me, I'm just trying to make a function that calls all the sentences to invoke the function from somewhere and automate it. The select that sent the error I deduce that initializes the sequence based on the value of another table, the statement is:
SELECT setval ('seq_temporal', (select (min (ID) * -1) + 1 from OTHER_TABLE)); La solución de fue usar PERFORM: PERFORM setval ('seq_temporal', (select (min (ID) * -1) + 1 from OTHER_TABLE));

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense to execute as a `PERFORM`. The `SELECT` you posted in your question didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> query has no destination for result data Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

You are getting this error because you do not assign the results to any variable in the function.  In a function, you would typically do something like this instead:

```
select * into var1 from MY_TABLE;
```

Therefore, your function would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createTable() RETURNS int AS $$
     DECLARE
       var1 my_table%ROWTYPE;
     BEGIN
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE; 
          CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
            (
                    ID integer
            )
             WITH (
                OIDS=FALSE
            );

            insert into MY_TABLE values(1);

            select * into var1 from MY_TABLE;
            <do something with var1>
            RETURN 'SUCCESS';
     END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Otherwise, if you don't put the results into a variable, then you're likely hoping to achieve some side effect (like advancing a sequence or firing a trigger somehow).  In that case, plpgsql expects you to use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`

Also, BTW your function `RETURNS int` but at the bottom of your definition you `RETURN 'SUCCESS'`.  `SUCCESS` is a `text` type, not an `int`, so you will eventually get this error once you get past that first error message -- be sure to change it as necessary.

Comment: What's the point of putting it into a variable if the variable is not used anywhere?

Comment: That’s what we are trying to figure out. Other people have mentioned you should either take it out or do something with it. If you are trying to return it, perhaps you can return it instead of the string `SUCCESS`. I’m just trying to help you understand the error and figure out a way to get past it. You need to make the necessary changes to match your requirements

Comment: Thanks richyen, in fact it is what I mainly can't understand by not knowing the pgsql rules that apply
 to the functions. I thought I could execute any statement that I executed on the IDE within a function. Now I understand that any SQL query must be assigned to a variable, just as in other languages ​​you cannot have literals without assigning a variable. For a query that is not going to be assigned to a variable, I must use PERFORM.